# Printing column after column

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm trying to make my page printer friendly, I have a page that contains 3 columns in body with 2 photos in 2nd column and a table in footer. I need it to be printed every paragraph under paragraph, photo under photo, so it wouldn't print just those 3 columns as I see it in my browser, but all page would print as 1 column.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ah, best to show all of your code as otherwise it will cause confusion to those trying to help

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to unpack here.  It would help to know what your code looks like right now. Without that however I would suggest looking at the following.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

This allows you to define css rules for printing.

https://getbootstrap.com/

This is one of the most used CSS libraries on the net and is very helpful in creating responsive layouts.

If this doest get you going in the right direction, provide some code for the community to look at to help understand what you have done already.

Good Luck